# Как получить данные из ответа Retrofit2 по вложенностям

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

Доступ к ответы идет через response.body , но это если у нас не вложенный JSON. А как мне обратиться к данным, которые имеют вложенность. Вот пример
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот так выглядят две модели. Они разбиты по разным файлам
Первая вложенность

```
public class BasePojo {
    @SerializedName("page")
    @Expose
    private int page;
    @SerializedName("total_results")
    @Expose
    private int totalResults;
    @SerializedName("total_pages")
    @Expose
    private int totalPages;
    @SerializedName("results")
    @Expose
    private ArrayList<ResultsPojo> results;

    public BasePojo(ArrayList<ResultsPojo> results, int page){
        this.results = results;
        this.page = page;
    }

    public int getPage() {
        return page;
    }

    public void setPage(int page) {
        this.page = page;
    }

    public int getTotalResults() {
        return totalResults;
    }

    public void setTotalResults(int totalResults) {
        this.totalResults = totalResults;
    }

    public int getTotalPages() {
        return totalPages;
    }

    public void setTotalPages(int totalPages) {
        this.totalPages = totalPages;
    }

    public ArrayList<ResultsPojo> getResults() {
        return results;
    }

    public void setResults(ArrayList<ResultsPojo> results) {
        this.results = results;
    }
    }
```

Вторая вложенность

```
 public class ResultsPojo {

    @SerializedName("vote_count")
    @Expose
    private int voteCount;
    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    private int id;
    @SerializedName("video")
    @Expose
    private boolean video;
    @SerializedName("vote_average")
    @Expose
    private double voteAverage;
    @SerializedName("title")
    @Expose
    private String title;
    @SerializedName("popularity")
    @Expose
    private double popularity;
    @SerializedName("poster_path")
    @Expose
    private String posterPath;
    @SerializedName("original_language")
    @Expose
    private String originalLanguage;
    @SerializedName("original_title")
    @Expose
    private String originalTitle;
    @SerializedName("genre_ids")
    @Expose
    private List<Integer> genreIds = null;
    @SerializedName("backdrop_path")
    @Expose
    private String backdropPath;
    @SerializedName("adult")
    @Expose
    private boolean adult;
    @SerializedName("overview")
    @Expose
    private String overview;
    @SerializedName("release_date")
    @Expose
    private String releaseDate;

    public int getVoteCount() {
        return voteCount;
    }

    public void setVoteCount(int voteCount) {
        this.voteCount = voteCount;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public boolean isVideo() {
        return video;
    }

    public void setVideo(boolean video) {
        this.video = video;
    }

    public double getVoteAverage() {
        return voteAverage;
    }

    public void setVoteAverage(double voteAverage) {
        this.voteAverage = voteAverage;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public double getPopularity() {
        return popularity;
    }

    public void setPopularity(double popularity) {
        this.popularity = popularity;
    }

    public String getPosterPath() {
        return posterPath;
    }

    public void setPosterPath(String posterPath) {
        this.posterPath = posterPath;
    }

    public String getOriginalLanguage() {
        return originalLanguage;
    }

    public void setOriginalLanguage(String originalLanguage) {
        this.originalLanguage = originalLanguage;
    }

    public String getOriginalTitle() {
        return originalTitle;
    }

    public void setOriginalTitle(String originalTitle) {
        this.originalTitle = originalTitle;
    }

    public List<Integer> getGenreIds() {
        return genreIds;
    }

    public void setGenreIds(List<Integer> genreIds) {
        this.genreIds = genreIds;
    }

    public String getBackdropPath() {
        return backdropPath;
    }

    public void setBackdropPath(String backdropPath) {
        this.backdropPath = backdropPath;
    }

    public boolean isAdult() {
        return adult;
    }

    public void setAdult(boolean adult) {
        this.adult = adult;
    }

    public String getOverview() {
        return overview;
    }

    public void setOverview(String overview) {
        this.overview = overview;
    }

    public String getReleaseDate() {
        return releaseDate;
    }

    public void setReleaseDate(String releaseDate) {
        this.releaseDate = releaseDate;
    }
}
```

Comment: у вас просто массив возвращается, надо сначала обратиться к 0 элементу, тогда получите объект, если добавите код, которым разбираете данный запрос, то могу дать ответ точнее.

Comment: Вам необходимо описать 2 модели. Первая будет содержать в себе поле второй модели, в Ваше случае будет поле со списком второй модели.

Answer (score 2):

С использованием аннотаций Gson ответ будет выглядеть так:

```
public class AnyResponse {

    @Nullable
    @SerializedName("page")
    public Integer page;

    @Nullable
    @SerializedName("total_results")
    public Integer totalResults;

    @Nullable
    @SerializedName("total_pages")
    public Integer totalPages;

    @Nullable
    @SerializedName("results")
    public List<Result> results;

    public class Result {

       @Nullable
       @SerializedName("vote_count")
       public Integer voteCount;

       @Nullable
       @SerializedName("title")
       public String title;

       // и прочие поля...

    }

}
```

Функция должна иметь тип `Call<AnyResponse>`, тогда в коллбэке `response.body` будет иметь тип `AnyResponse`, где вы без проблем сможете обратиться к каждому элементу вашего списка `response.body.results`

Comment: То есть нужно в одном классе POJO сделать вложенность. А я по туториалам почему то создавал два разных файла POJO.

Comment: Попробовал, но почему то доступов все равно нет к нужным полям.

Comment: @BorisRuzanov, а поля класса `BasePojo` десериализуются нормально?